# An issue with Installing C connector to the Weil McLain boiler

Tags: thermostat, heating, thermostat-c-wire

I'm trying to install a `C` connector to my Weil McLain boiler. The `C` connector instruction seems simple. Just connect all `W`s to `W`s, and `R`s to `R`s as the picture below.

[image]

but the wiring in my boiler seems different. `R` comes from `Y` port and `W` comes from `G` port.

[image]

This configuration has been working with my old thermostat anyway, and it's same as the boiler installation guide on the panel.

[image]

I wonder if it okay to keep this configuration and link `C` wire additionally to the `C` connector. So, it will be `Y` to `R`, `G` to `W`, and `C` to `C`.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!!
Thank you!!

P.S here's the full shots of the wiring and the diagram:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: it looks likee the wiring board is screwed to the transformer, C will be the terminal that is neither R nor W,  but I ca't see enought to be exactly sure.  zoom the thriord photo ut to show more. and zoom the second in to show more detail of the back of the transformer.

Comment: What model/series is your boiler, and can you post a full shot of its wiring diagram for that matter?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your opinions. I attached the full shots of the wiring diagram. I'm not sure which one is the transformer. I just added more pictures. The boiler Model is `EG/PEG 40-PIDN`, and the Series No is `5`.

Answer (score 1):

It's the one with all the green (teal) wires plugged onto it,  I think you've labeled it "C" already.